# Send e-mail to multiple contacts as as separate mails

Tags: email

If I do a search, and then want to send en e-mail to the resulting contacts, (by using "**Send mail**", not by using "Send Mass Mailing") all of the contacts get put in the "To:" field.

But I want to either

- send all these e-mails separately. (x e-mails, with only 1 recipient per e-mail
- or put these recipients in the **BCC:** field instead of the **To:**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the previous answer states correctly, CiviCRM does in fact send individual emails to each contact you selected. The simplest way to know this is thats the only way tokens would work properly. If everyone was just to'd in one big list they'd all see one set of tokens (mail merge fields) which would not be correct.

If you wish to add others then you can using the BCC and CC fields but they'll get copied into every single email i.e. if 50 contacts are emailed then they'll get copied into those 50 emails.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try? Because if I'm right CiviCRM does show all in the To, but actually sends them separately.

Even in Send Mail you can have token replacement, and that would not be possible if only one mail would be sent.